# How to inject controller in another module

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

I want to inject a controller into other module. I have two files

- index.html
- app.js

the code of index.html is below

```
<body  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <h1>{{lab}}</h1>
   <h1 ng-controller="secCtrl">{{lab2}}</h1>
</body>
```

and app.js is as below

```
var myapi = angular.module('mainApp', []);

myapi.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.lab='Hello'
    return{
        controller:'secCtrl'
    }   
});

myapi.controller('secCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.lab2='Hello you are secCtrl'    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some clarification needed :**

- What do you mean by `inject a controller into other module` `?`
- No need to use return statement inside `mainCtrl` as per your code structure.

**DEMO**

```js
var myapi = angular.module('mainApp', []);

myapi.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.lab='Hello';
});

myapi.controller('secCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.lab2='Hello you are secCtrl'    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <h1>{{lab}}</h1>
   <h1 ng-controller="secCtrl">{{lab2}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If the question needs clarification, just don't answer it until it is clear enough. Bad questions result in bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what do you mean by `inject controller in another module` , but if you want share data beetween two module , you can use `services`

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
 var message= [];
 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }
 function set(mes) {
   message.push(mes)
 }
 function get() {
  return message;
 }



});
```

In ctrl1

```
myapi.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,myService){

$scope.lab='Hello'
  myService.set($scope.lab);
});
```

In ctrl2

```
myapi.controller('secCtrl', function($scope,myService) {
    $scope.lab2= myService.get();

});
```

Comment: i dont want to use factory or  service is there another way ?

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed yes , you can use $rootScope